# Create push notification when value in firebase database change

Tags: ios, database, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send a push notification to the user when a value in my firebase database change. this is my database

```
{
  "Battles" : {
    "00000111-062B3333-4046-4FB4-AA37-C2B05853E497" : {
      "BattleProgress" : "",
      "Player1" : "lzsPuNwHbIZI1J8k40FspYRV4XQ2",
      "Player2" : "tHNBif9csWNCOuftAGLAqvLWNUw1",
      "Score" : "0-0",
      "Turn" : 1
    }
  },
  "users" : {
    "lzsPuNwHbIZI1J8k40FspYRV4XQ2" : {
      "Coins" : 1,
      "Dollars" : 0,
      "FBID" : “ID”,
      "GamesLost" : 0,
      "GamesWon" : 0,
      "name" : “Name”
    },
    "tHNBif9csWNCOuftAGLAqvLWNUw1" : {
      "Coins" : 0,
      "Dollars" : 0,
      "FBID" : “ID”,
      "GamesLost" : 0,
      "GamesWon" : 0,
      "name" : “Name”
    }
  }
}
```

So lets say, the value of "Turn" changes, then I want a push notification sent out to the player whos turn it is. But how can I check if the value of "Turn" changes when the user shuts down the app?

I've read a bit about Firebase Cloud Messaging, but cant seem to find the answar...

Comment: You will need to set up a so-called app server that listens to the database, detects the change and then send a downstream message to the offline user. See this recent [blog post about a similar scenario](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html). Though the post talks about Android, the same approach could be applied to iOS.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Firebase using Cloud Functions. Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events for more information.