# Send message to web client when value in database has changed

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, client-side, google-cloud-functions

Between making a payment and receiving a payment confirmation, the user sees a page with the text 'processing your payment' and a loading icon. When the payment is complete, the value of hasPaid changes to 'true' in my Firebase database.

When the value changes, a confirmation email is send to the user via a cloud function but if the user is still on the waiting page I want to show a confirmation message. So can I send an event to my web client side when this value has changed or is it only possible to send a request to my database every x seconds?

Comment: You could simply have the web client listen for that value in the database. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a database sending a notification to a client side javascript function is even possible, as you wouldn't know the IP address to send the notification to.

You *can* send push notifications when a value in firebase changes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43571639/850326) (and question):

> You can do this with Firebase using Cloud Functions. Check out
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases and
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events for more
>   information.

You can also simply poll the database every second to see if that value changes in your JS client-side code, and if it does, post a message on the site.